# Cypress to get only href in a page that contains specific path inside

Tags: cypress, href

I am trying to make a test that actually look into all the `href` in a page, and ONLY if the path url contains `/example` (mywebsite.com/example/anotherPage) inside the href, I want to test the url.

```js
describe('VerifyProductsLinks', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('a').each((page) => {
      if (page.prop('href').should('contains', '/example')) {
        cy.request(page.prop('href'))
      }
    })
  })
})
```

This is what I tried, but I get the error **page.prop is not a function**. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cypress to collect all `a` elements (assuming those are the ones with hrefs), iterate through them with `cy.each()`, and then only take actions if the element's href contains a certain value (by using the yielded element, JQuery's `.prop()` function, and JavaScript String `.includes()`.

```js
cy.get('a').each(($a) => {
  if ($a.prop('href').includes('/example') {
    // cypress code here
    cy.request($a.prop('href'));
  }
});
```

Attempting to do an `if/else` on a Cypress command directly will not work as expected, as these commands do not yield a boolean value to be evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an `.each()` and `if()`.

Instead you could change the Cypress subject from the element to the attribute using `.invoke()`

```js
cy.get('a[href*="/example"]')
  .invoke('attr', 'href')
  .then(href => {
    cy.request(href)
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a filter function on the `<a>` elements.  IMO me this is the tidiest way.

Also note `page.prop()` is not *always* the same as `page.attr()`, which is the preferred way of extracting an attribute value.

```js
cy.get('a')
  .filter('[href*="/example"]')
  .each((page) => {
    cy.request(page.attr('href'))
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [jquery attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to only return anchors with the matching value.

In your example it would look like this

```js
cy.get('a[href*="/example"]')
  .should('have.length.gte', 1)
  // map out only hrefs
  .then(h => Cypress._.map(h, el => el.href))
  .each(href => {
    cy.request(href)
    // any other code
  })
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/commit/63bf6ac3e3a2a4debefdeafcb054bd441bbc4352) for getting hrefs containing a value.